# How to prepare development environment under openSUSE?

Tags: cross-compilation

I need to prepare development environment for AVR8 and RaspberryPi. I have installed AVR toolchain from http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/CrossToolchain:/avr/. Where to get cross-compiler for RaspberryPi? I have used `armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi` via crossdev under Gentoo, what is analogue for one under openSUSE?

P.S. [This repository](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Ports:/ARM:/Base:/build:/cross/) contains some crosscompiler stuff related ARMv5 and ARMv7, others seems to be devoted to running openSUSE under ARM itself.

P.P.S. Is [this](http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/) a good way to install RPi cross-compiler under openSUSE?

Comment: `crosstool-ng` (from your P.P.S link) can create a  cross compiler that works with the pi.  I think the instructions in that particular blog are a little thin tho.  If you do go that root, there are no distro specific differences, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to setup your crosscompiler on your on. There are already crosscompiler for the Raspi available.

There are three compilers available: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools

and a good tutorial to start with: http://hertaville.com/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler.html

btw. the tutorial is written for (k)ubuntu but you can also use it for opensuse. You can download the git-repo (there is a button with a cloud and 'zip' written on it) from the website, 'install' and link it somewhere in the system.